# Create new string every second - using String.Format or StringBuilder?

Tags: c#, wpf, stopwatch, string.format

So I have this class:

```
public class ElapsedTime: BaseObservableObject
{
    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;
    private static Stopwatch _stopWatch;
    private static string _value;

    public static Stopwatch StopWatch
    {
        get { return _stopWatch; }
        set
        {
            _stopWatch = value;
        }
    }

    public static string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            OnStaticPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    private static void OnStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Update my `Lebel`:

```
private void UpdateElapsedTime()
{
    string str = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}:{3:00}",
        ElapsedTime.StopWatch.Elapsed.Days,
        ElapsedTime.StopWatch.Elapsed.Hours,
        ElapsedTime.StopWatch.Elapsed.Minutes,
        ElapsedTime.StopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds);
    lblEl.content = str;
}
```

Does it allocate new memory each call (every one second) and its better to use `StringBuilder` ?

Comment: Creating a string every second is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.builder is for when you're looping many times adding a string to something you already have. You're creating a new string each time and sticking only a few strings together so it's not worth the effort. It might even have a higher overhead since the stringbuilder itself is more expensive to create than a string.

The difference between formatting 4 variables as you have now and one string format will be like a nanosecond so I wouldn't worry about that if you feel it's clearer as you have.
Clarity of code is often much more important than efficiency in a desktop app.

Why I'm posting an answer rather than a comment is because string interpolation is easier to use than format with numbering the variables.
Generally speaking anyhow.
The one format is much more elegant in this specific case and so this option is not better for your specific purpose.
I'd like to point out string interpolation exists though.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Which would look like:

```
lblEl.content = $"{ElapsedTime.StopWatch.Elapsed.Days:00}:{ElapsedTime.StopWatch.Elapsed.Hours:00}:{ElapsedTime.StopWatch.Elapsed.Minutes:00}:{ElapsedTime.StopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds:00}";
```

I most often use this in debugging when I want to see a bunch of variables and just a break point and quick watch is impractical.

Note that you can include a format by appending ":" then the usual format string after a variable.

Comment: And what the different between my code and the one you posted here ?

Comment: BTW now my label looks like 0:0:0:0 instead of 00:00:00:00 which is what i want it to be

Comment: I've edited my post to show how you format strings with string interpolation. In this particular case, Ash's suggestion is simpler.

Comment: every time you access `StopWatch.Elapsed` - you get new value. access it 4 times -> 4 different results

Comment: You're right. And I think the one format is a better solution for his specific purpose. But... way less than a second will pass between getting the day, hour, minute and second. Probably less than a millisecond.

Answer (score 2):

use ToString overload which accept format string argument. 1 ToString call per second is very cheap in terms of resources

```
private void UpdateElapsedTime()
{
    lblEl.content = ElapsedTime.StopWatch.Elapsed.ToString(@"dd\:hh\:mm\:ss");
}
```

Comment: This is a simpler solution for the OP's specific purpose.  I intended my post to explain string interpolation.